HP stuck in BitLocker recovery
I was given a PC by the pastor of our church to refresh for our children's ministry. The PC has been sitting unused in the sound booth for 2 years. No one knows the bitlocker key or where the key may be stored or even what MS account is tied to it. Looking to wipe the entire drive, start fresh, but bitlocker has this thing locked up tight as a dolphins butthole. There's no need to keep the data that's on it, I planned on wiping it anyhow. How do I tell bitlocker to go away and let me wipe the drive? Even when I try wiping it from the EFI partition, it just errors and reboots to the bitlocker key request. Trying to save the budget from having to buy a new PC. Can anyone impart their wisdom on how to do this?

Without the BitLocker key there is no solution other than a clean install of Windows. The existence of BitLocker shouldn’t prevent the deletion of all partitions on the drive. You tell BitLocker to “go away” by deleting all partitions on the drive. You mention an error but specify the error.

This is a pretty standard case of just needing to do a full wipe and reinstall. This is a very well documented process. What research have you done so far? How did you try to wipe it? How are you getting into EFI to wipe? Have you tried creating a bootable disk and wiping that way? If not, why not?

This question is similar to: Wiping a computer before re-imaging. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The PC is a HP Envy. I tried booting into the EFI but it gives me a blue screen saying "Windows has encountered an error" No message or code attached to it at all. Same thing happened when I made a media instalation tool boot disk from my working PC(w11). I think I'm going to have to go Dr. Moishe's route. To do this I'm going to have to pick up another USB drive as I only have the one I made the w11 boot disk with. I'll update when done if it works out or if not. Thanks for the comments yall.


Create a bootable USB device that has some drive utilities, such as Gnome Disks or Windows DiskGenius. Some examples:

Hiren’s BootCD PE, which contains AOMEI Partition Assistant, DiskGenius and other disk partitioning tools.
Ultimate Boot CD, which contains Cute Partition Manager, GParted and other disk partitioning tools
Ubuntu Live, which contains Gnome Disks.


Boot from the USB drive. Details on booting depend on the PC, which are omitted from the question. You would need to find a manual for that PC online, find out how to enter BIOS setup, make changes to BIOS to enable booting from USB, and change boot order.
Use a drive utility to remove all partitions on the internal drive. Most utilities require that you commit each change after starting it.
Shut down the PC.
Create installation media for the intended operating system, such as Windows 10, or Windows 11, or Ubuntu. Note that Windows 10 support ends in Oct 2025, so if the PC cannot run Windows 11, consider Linux OS.
Now boot from the media created in 5. to install a permanent operating system.


Thank you sir! This seems to be the route I'm going to have to take, though I'll have to dredge up another USB drive. I will post here again if it works to help the community if they encounter a similar issue.
